# Android Blank screen Problem

Tags: android, progressdialog

I m forwarding control from Activity1 to Activity2

In Activity2 
  i am using progressDialog in onCreate before setContentView

after some network operation i am using setcontentView

but progressDialog is not showing at all...

how to archive progressDialog.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider adding code you're working on to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please post some code so that we can be sure, but I'm betting its because of your network operation.  As with my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867317/why-doesnt-my-toast-show-up/4867363#4867363) about toast messages, when you make a call to create a dialog, I think you are *requesting* that the UI thread create a dialog, it doesn't necessarily happen as soon as the `show()` method returns.  If you then perform a network operation in `onCreate` then this will block the UI thread until it completes, preventing the `Dialog` from appearing.  You should move any network requests out into either an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`/`Handler` combination.

- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)
- [Threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading)
- [Designing for responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)
- [Thread documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Handler documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to call show() of ProgressDialog:

```
    ProgressDialog dialogLoad;
    dialogLoad = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);

    //doing work
    //when done with work
    dialogLoad.dismiss();
```

===============================

Think about using threads too:

```
ProgressDialog dialogLoad;
    dialogLoad = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);

final Handler handler = new Handler() {
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              dialogLoad.dismiss();
              }
           };
        Thread updateData = new Thread() {  
           public void run() {

           //************make calls to web service/network***************

              handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
              }
           };
          updateData.start();
```